# HTML to check if RTMP stream is live

Tags: rtmp

Anyone know how I can check to see if a RTMP stream is online or not?

Streams are like rtmp://ip/user/stream, "user" being the different streams.

Any advise on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: HTML cannot do this alone you will need something like javascript and ajax methods and handle repsone on callback, or a server side language that will check the stream and output the correct html to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow this is old.

Fixed this many moons ago using AS3 on the server side to request from the web server with variables to tell the database if the stream is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a way of doing this just using HTML. You can use rtmpdump if you want to get a little technical:
http://blog.svnlabs.com/how-to-check-rtmp-source-stream-is-live-or-not/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN-UYi0UVGE